# Translating DataGridView text at runtime in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, translation, translate

I am struggling with finding a way to translate text of my `DataGridView`(the last 4 headers of columns out of 5, and a whole column). This `DataGridView` is only used as a template for the user to fill, it is not changing the Microsoft Access file or anything, it just serves for the user to fill out it's checkboxes and then print what has been checked into an Excel file.

I've tried to load another `DataGridView` and mess with the Designer.cs of it's form but to no success. I've also tried messing with the `FormX_Load` but to no aveil as well.

This is how I am translating the rest of my code

```
    private void changeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.IetfLanguageTag)
        {
            case "pt-PT":
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture
          = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"); break;

            case "en-US":
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture
          = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-PT"); break;

            default:
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture
               = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"); break;
        }
```

I changed the language of the forms by the properties and applied this code, it worked just fine, now the problem is, I want to change the language of my datagridview at runtime either by loading another database or changing the cultureinfo with code.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I am not following if the language translation works or not. When you state… _”…this one worked too but is interfering with the code below”_ ? … How is this “interfering” with the grids `CellValueChanged` event? Do you get an error?... Below this code you state… _”The problem that the index received is not within the parameters”_ … ? What do you mean by this? What index “received”? And within “what” parameters. Forgive me if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: I am sorry, maybe I added too much code without explain, the first block of code is working to translate everything except for the DGV, no errors
I meant to say that I also tried the second block of code but it interferes with the third one

Comment: Your last comment is not much help. Can you please re-read my first comment and do your best answer the questions I asked?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry for my incomplete answer. ”The problem that the index received is not within the parameters” this was the error I got a couple days ago while trying to implement the second block of code (instead of the first), I assumed that that error was happening in the third block of code that I posted. I don't know specifically if it was referring to the ColumnIndex or the RowIndex or even what parameters. I am sorry for not giving a more complete answer but my knowledge limits me.

Comment: I think I will remove the  2nd and 3rd blocks of code since I can already translate all of the program except for the DGV, I was just trying to show what routes I tried to take

Comment: @JohnG I am really open to any kind of solution, really desperate for help because I can't seem to find anyone trying to accomplish the same thing when i search online